# a problem with solving an example on nasm

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

x^3/2+1
if x=2 the answer it gives is 4290776301. i tried to do anything i could and i think the problem might be in ascii decoding or smth but i don't know what else i can do here.

```
%include "in_out.asm"
SECTION .data
msg: DB 'Вариант 6. Мой пример: f(x) = x*x*x/2 + 1.Введи, какой x я бы поставил: ', 0
pink: DB 'Ответ на пример: ', 0

SECTION .bss
x: resb 80

SECTION .text
GLOBAL _start
_start:

mov eax, msg
call sprintLF

mov ecx, x
mov edx, 80
call sread


mov eax, x
call atoi

mov ebx, [x]
mov eax, x
mul ebx
mul ebx
mov ebx, 2
xor ebx, edx
div ebx
add eax, 1
mov [x],eax

mov eax, pink
call sprint

mov eax, [x]
call iprintLF

call quit
```

looking forward for any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### if x=2 the answer it gives is 4290776301

- > ```
  > mov eax, x
  > mul ebx
  > ```

  The result can get so big because you are not starting the multiplication from the inputted number but rather from the address of the buffer *x*. In NASM `mov eax, x` loads the address of *x*, and `mov eax, [x]` loads the value stored at *x*.
- > ```
  > call atoi
  > mov ebx, [x]
  > mov eax, x
  > ```

  *atoi* already leaves its result in the `EAX` register. You only need to copy it to the `EBX` register. `call atoi` `mov ebx, eax`.
- > ```
  > mov ebx, 2
  > xor ebx, edx
  > div ebx
  > ```

  For the division by 2, you needed to clear the `EDX` register. You've accidently (typo) XORed the divider instead! And of course, dividing by 2 is better done using a shift to the right `shr eax, 1`.

### A solution

```
mov  eax, msg
call sprintLF

mov  eax, x
call scanf

mov  eax, x
call atoi      ; -> EAX

mov  ebx, eax  ; ((X^3)/2)+1
imul ebx, eax
imul ebx, eax
shr  ebx, 1
inc  ebx

mov  eax, pink
call sprint

mov  eax, ebx
call iprintLF
```